# Does DataTable implement IListSource?

Tags: .net, interface, interface-implementation

The documentation (and intellisense) states very clearly that `DataTable` implements `IListSource`. But then why doesn't `DataTable` have a `getList()` method, which is (the main) part of the `IListView` interface?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`DataTable` uses [Explicit Interface Implementation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173157.aspx) to implement `IListSource`.

You can still use the method via:

```
 IListSource listSource = (IListSource)dataTable;
 IList list = listSource.GetList();
```